# How to restrict the input in a NumberTextfield according to the locale conventions

Tags: javafx, locale, number-formatting

I am using a NumberTextfield class extending the Textfield class.
It accepts numbers and dots but no commas.
The language of my programm can be switched from english to german, so
I would like to have the a possibility to adapt the input of numbers to the national conventions.

I know that this topic has been covered and I am actually using a pattern I found on Stackoverflow, but it covers the english type of formatting.
I tried a lot of regex patterns I found on the ne, but none seems to work.

As you might have guessed I am quite new to Java.
It would be great if somone could help me.

I tried a lot of regex patterns I found on the net, but none of them seems to work.
Setting the locale does not seem to have any effects (or it may be shadowed by the regex in the NumberTextfield).

Here is the code of my NumberTextField:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class NumberTextField extends TextField {

 private static Pattern decimalPattern = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]*(\\,[0-9]*)?");

@Override
public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
    if (validate(start, text)) {
        super.replaceText(start, end, text);
    }
}

@Override
public void replaceSelection(String text) {
if (validate(Integer.MAX_VALUE, text)) {
    super.replaceSelection(text);
    }
}

private boolean validate(int start, String text) {
String currentText = (getText()==null) ? "" : getText();
if(start == 0) { //to handle "-1.1" or ".1" cases
    return decimalPattern.matcher(text + currentText).matches();  
    } 
else {
    return decimalPattern.matcher(currentText + text).matches();
    }
}
```

}

This is the code in the initialize() of my controller:

```
Glob.setLangID("de");
java.util.Locale locale=new java.util.Locale("de_DE");
```

Comment: you are on wrong tracks: a) never-ever do any manual pattern matching on Locale-dependent entities, instead use the corresponding Format - here that would be one returned from NumberFormat b) don't re-invent the wheel - TextField has a property TextFormatter for exactly the purpose you need :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still do not know how to solve the problem.